# chaining jquery methods and arguments in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to build a few DOM elements from scratch using jquery and coffeescript... The problem is keeping the readability of the jquery chain and the correct use of newlines and intends in coffeescript...

For example I have a `<div>` element I want to append some `<p>` elements, style them, add some attributes and add eventhandler. In pure javascript I would do something like this:

```js
var elem = $("<div">)
  .append($("<p>")
    .css({"color":"red"})
    .attr("id", "pElement")
    .text("example text...")
  )
  .append($("<p>")
    .css({"font-weight":"bold"})
    .text("example text...")
    .on("click", document, function() {
      alert("clicked");
    })
  );
```

But "porting" this example to coffeescript like:

```js
elem = $("<div">)
  .append $("<p>")
    .css
       color:"red"
    .attr "id", "pElement"
    .text "example text..."
  .append $("<p>")
    .css
      font-weight:"bold"
    .text "example text..."
    .on "click", document, ->
      alert "clicked"
```

does not compile to correct javascript...

What is the correct way "porting" the example to coffeescript?

Comment: [Looks like it's still sort of an open problem.](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/1495)

Comment: Leave some parentheses in so that the nesting isn't so confusing? Or better, build the `<p>`s in separate variables and append them so that, again, the structure is clearer and CoffeeScript won't get confused by your intention.

Comment: The separate variables definitively works. I'll try the suggestion of @jcollum and if that may be too "unstructured", I'll keep the separate variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to put any chained function calls at the beginning of the next line, so it's very obvious that that line is part of a chain. Depending on the length of the next function call I may chain it on the same line.

```
elem = $('<div>').append($('<p>')
.css('color': 'red')
.attr('id', 'pElement')
.text('example text...'))
.append($('<p>').css('font-weight': 'bold')
.text('example text...').on('click', document, ->
  alert 'clicked' 
))
```

This transpiles to:

```
var elem;

elem = $('<div>').append($('<p>').css({
'color': 'red'
}).attr('id', 'pElement').text('example text...')).append($('<p>').css({
  'font-weight': 'bold'
}).text('example text...').on('click', document, function() {
  alert('clicked');
}));
```

Apparently this is contrary to the style guides that are out there. They recommend indenting chained calls. To me, an indent means a "block" (function, if/else, etc.) and chaining doesn't feel like a "block" to me. I think it reads better without the indent.

Comment: I tried leaving parentheses around the function calls, but coffee doesn't like to compile it... but maybe missed something using parentheses and indention... I'll try your suggestion the next days and give you a feedback...

Comment: This works as expected, in my project I use a combination of this solution and the hint of @mu is too short...